# Viewing NetApp cluster NFS shares

Tags: netapp

I've managed to inherit a NetApp system and could do with some pointers for basic tasks. It looks like we may need to get a consultant in, but I don't see why checking these simple things should be this difficult...

First of all the system is running live NFS services for VMWare, but I can not get any info on the NFS configuration. I'm hoping this would at least give me some info on what volumes are doing what (as even they don't make sense, see below).

It shows 4 vservers, with 2 nodes -

```
                           Admin      Operational Root
Vserver     Type    Subtype    State      State       Volume     Aggregate
----------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
SAN2        admin   -          -          -           -          -
SAN2-01     node    -          -          -           -          -
SAN2-02     node    -          -          -           -          -
svm_nfs_sm
            data    default    running    running     svm_nfs_   san2_01_
                                                      sm_root    data
```

However, trying to list any nfs settings, with or without a vserver specified, just returns nothing

```
SAN2::> nfs show
This table is currently empty.

SAN2::> nfs show -vserver svm_nfs_sm
There are no entries matching your query.
```

Also regarding volumes, as briefly mentioned above, even they don't make much sense. I'm seeing 3 NFS mounts in VMware, reported as 3TB, 3TB & 1TB, but only 2 2.5TB volumes on the NetApp

```
svm_nfs_sm
          vmdatastore01_sm
                       san2_01_data
                                    online     DP       2.50TB    824.8GB   67%
svm_nfs_sm
          vmdatastore02_sm
                       san2_02_data
                                    online     DP       2.50TB     1.23TB   50%
```

I could do with some basic help to just try and inventory what is doing what, and where the data from VMWare is actually being stored...